# jQuery selector not working after toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I only want the inactive (red) switch to be clicked on but the jQuery Selector isn't working as expected after the classes are toggled.

I also tried ".live"... What am I missing here?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojpdf

markup:

```
<div class="controls group">
  <span class="switch inactive"></span>
  <span class="switch"></span>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.inactive').on('click', function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("inactive");
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass("inactive");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.controls').on('click','.switch', function(){
      $('.switch').toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).on('click', '.inactive', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("inactive");
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("inactive");
});
```

Comment: wouldn't that make both switches clickable?// edit: second options works. thanks